# java , each Json documents stored in a List of String for elastic search

Tags: java, json, maven, elasticsearch

I am novice in java and I am using elasticsearch and I am looking a way to put Json's documents in a List string. The things is, I want to read a Json file  and then stored each Json's documents in a List String :

Example: 
  readTheJsonfile = (src/main/resource/file.json)

and then for example:

```
 <
```

`List <String > readTheJsonfile [1] = "{\n" +
                                "    \"user\" : \"stack\",\n" +
                                "    \"post_date\" : \"2009-11-15T14:12:12\",\n" +
                                "    \"message\" : \"trying search\"\n" +
                                "}"

List <String > readTheJsonfile [2] = "{\n" +
                                "    \"user\" : \"flow\",\n" +
                                "    \"post_date\" : \"2009-11-15T14:12:12\",\n" +
                                "    \"message\" : \"trying Ela\"\n" +
                                "}"`

>

Comment: Am i correct to assume you want to take a JSON input and decoding it into different objects? In that case use a library like jsonsimple/gson etc...

Comment: Found a example for you [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/)... Next time try to find it on your own. Simple googling of "how to decode JSON in java" will with most certainty give you satisfying results

Comment: thanks you  very much!!!